# How to get Expo static deep link for development?

Tags: react-native, expo, amazon-cognito, deep-linking

I need an Expo static deep link for development to use for Oauth redirect with a 3rd party ( Cognito )

I have used `Linking.makeUrl()` but this returns a deep link with a dynamic local ipaddress
exp://10.0.0.107:19000 that will not be consistent for other developers on the team.

The documentation at:
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/linking/#linking-module

Says the various environment links look like

- *Published app in Expo client* :  `exp://exp.host/@community/with-webbrowser-redirect`
- *Published app in standalone* :  `myapp://`
- *Development* :  `exp://wg-qka.community.app.exp.direct:80`

I have tried that Development link but it fails to open.

Comment: Look at https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#a-note-for-expo-users

Comment: hmm so maybe `exp://127.0.0.1:19000` @oleg

Answer (score 5):

I have the similar issue too, here is my solution
Also post in https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/4244#issuecomment-586845322

In case anyone still needs help for expo+amplify+social logins

app.json

```js
{
  "expo": {
    "scheme": "exposchemeappname://"  // use any name you like, just make it unique
  }
}
```

App.js

```js
import { Linking } from 'expo';
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';

import awsconfig from './aws-exports';

const amplifyConfig = {
  ...awsconfig,
  oauth: {
    ...awsconfig.oauth,
    urlOpener: async (url, redirectUrl) => {
      // On Expo, use WebBrowser.openAuthSessionAsync to open the Hosted UI pages.
      const { type, url: newUrl } = await WebBrowser.openAuthSessionAsync(url, redirectUrl);

      if (type === 'success') {
        await WebBrowser.dismissBrowser();

        if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
          return Linking.openURL(newUrl);
        }
      }
    },
    options: {
      // Indicates if the data collection is enabled to support Cognito advanced security features. By default, this flag is set to true.
      AdvancedSecurityDataCollectionFlag: true
    },
  }
};

const expoScheme = "exposchemeappname://"
// Technically you need to pass the correct redirectUrl to the web browser.
let redirectUrl = Linking.makeUrl();
if (redirectUrl.startsWith('exp://1')) {
  // handle simulator(localhost) and device(Lan)
  redirectUrl = redirectUrl + '/--/';
} else
if (redirectUrl === expoScheme) {
  // dont do anything
} else {
  // handle the expo client
  redirectUrl = redirectUrl + '/'
}
amplifyConfig.oauth.redirectSignIn = redirectUrl;
amplifyConfig.oauth.redirectSignOut = redirectUrl;

Amplify.configure(amplifyConfig);
```

Make sure you add the following redirect urls to amplify `amplify auth update`

```sh
# development
exp://127.0.0.1:19000/--/
exp://192.168.1.101:19000/ # depends on your lan ip

# expo client
exp://exp.host/@[EXPO_ACCOUNT]/[EXPO_APPNAME]/

# expo scheme for standalone
exposchemeappname://
```

Answer (score 1):

#### you can use `Linking` module

install it by running: `expo install expo-linking`

import it at the top of your file: `import * as Linking from "expo-linking";`

and then use: `Linking.makeUrl();` to get the link to your app hosted by expo client

`console` it to see the url

Answer (score 1):

Update for 2023: Linking.makeUrl() has been deprecated and replaced with Linking.createUrl(). More info in docs: https://docs.expo.dev/guides/linking/?redirected